# How to extract lines based on a substring from two separate text files in python?

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have two text files. The first one is of the form:

```
K, 6
J, 5
L, 4
```

The second file has the form:

```
K_1, 6
K_2, 5
J_1, 4
J_2, 4
J_3, 5
L_1, 4
```

I need output of the form:

```
K_1, 6, 6, same
K_2, 5, 6, different
J_1, 4, 5, different
J_2, 4, 5, different
J_3, 5, 5, same
L_1, 4, 4, same
```

where each line starts with lines from second text file (first two values), then I have to pick the third value based on substring from the first text file (i.e for K_1, the substring is K and I need to pick value 6 from the first text file). If the values in each line are the same, then it should print "same" else print "different" on each line.

Finally I need a count of lines with "same" and count of lines with "different" in the output file.

I tried writing the following code, but it is not giving me the expected output:

```
m1 = open('TextFile_1.txt')
m2 = open('TextFile_2.txt')
result = open('Output.txt','w')

lookup_from = {}
l2=[]

for line1 in m1:
    z1 = line1.split(',')[0].strip()
    z2 = z1.split('_')[0].strip()
    z3 = line1.split(',')[1].strip()
    ZX = (z2, z1, z3)
    lookup_from[ZX] = 0

for line2 in m2:
    z11 = line2.split(',')[0].strip()
    z22 = z11.split('_')[0].strip()
    z33 = line2.split(',')[1].strip()
    if z22 in [x for x,_,_ in lookup_from]:
        z4 = (z22, z11, z33)
        z5 = z4 + tuple([x for _,_,x in lookup_from])
        l2.append(z5)

for i in l2:
    result.write(str(i)[1:-1]+'\n')
result.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all the complicated lookups if you create a simple key, value dict from the first file and then generate the output on the fly whilst reading the second file:

```
with open('TextFile_1.txt') as f1:
    lookup = dict([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')] for line in f1)

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as out:
    with open('TextFile_2.txt') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            k, v = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
            n = lookup[k.split('_')[0]]
            out.write(', '.join(
                [k, v, n, 'same' if v == n else 'different']) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
K_1, 6, 6, same
K_2, 5, 6, different
J_1, 4, 5, different
J_2, 4, 5, different
J_3, 5, 5, same
L_1, 4, 4, same
```

Comment: @SaraS Do the real files have some blank lines? My code works fine with the example files in your question. Or are there some keys in the second file that don't have a matching one in the second file? Please update your question and show the real input files.

Comment: One quick question: in the script, in which part are you comparing the keys from first and second file?

Comment: @SaraS In the line `n = lookup[k[0]]`. So `lookup` has the keys `K`, `J`, and `L`, and `k[0]` is the first letter of e.g. `K_1` in the second file. (PS: it would **really** help if you showed the exact format of the real files).

Comment: I have "K" in the first file and "K_1" in the second file. I need to search for "K" and get the value from 1st.

Comment: @SaraS That is exactly what my code does. I tested it with the example files in your question, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I saw your updated code just now. It is working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.read_csv()` to input your data replacing file1 and file2 below and then use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['K', 'J', 'L'],
                      'col2': [6, 5, 4]})

file2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['K_1', 'K_2','J_1', 'J_2', 'J_3', 'L_1'],
                      'col4': [6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4]})

file2['col1'] = file2.col3.str[0]

compare = file2.merge(file1)
del(compare['col1'])

compare['result'] = np.where(compare.col4 == compare.col2, 'same', 'different')

print(compare)
```

Output:

```
  col3  col4  col2     result
0  K_1     6     6       same
1  K_2     5     6  different
2  J_1     4     5  different
3  J_2     4     5  different
4  J_3     5     5       same
5  L_1     4     4       same
```